# Most rewarding path in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm faced with the following problem:

**Given**

- An undirected graph, where each edge E has:

  - Et - the time it takes to traverse E
  - Er - the reward for traversing E

**Goal:**

- Problem 1: Given time period T, find the most rewarding path in the graph
- Problem 2: Given time period T, find the most rewarding cycle in the graph (after period T, the agent must be at the start-point again).

**Notes:**

- If an edge is partially traversed, the reward is proportional the the portion traversed
- Reward can be claimed only once for each edge traversed (or portion of)
- A path/cycle may start at any given point (either on a vertex, or along an edge)

**My questions:**

- Is this a known problem (Does it has a name? Has it been studied before?).
- Is it NP-hard?
- Any ideas how to approach it?

**Known Related Problems:**

- [The orienteering problem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221710002973) - Rewards are vertex-based (). In my case, the rewards are edge-based.
- [Profitable Arc Tour Problem](http://www.citeulike.org/user/rchen/article/6012250) - The objective is to find a set of cycles in the graph that maximizes the collection of profit minus travel costs.
- **Edit:** [The Undirected Capacitated Arc Routing Problem with Profits](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305054809001452) - Quite similar to my problem, but a depot vertex (start,end of each cycle) is given, the triangle inequality is satisfied, and the problem is generalized to a set of agents, all starting and ending at the same depot).

Comment: I haven't see a question like this since grad school! Have you tried posting this at the Math Exchange, all the clever math beavers hang out there.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [cs.se] than [so].

Comment: @MarcAudet This is definitely not a maths question, but Matt might be right about being better suited for [cs.se].

Comment: 1: I think it is 2: yes. Given enough time, you'll be able to pass every vertex. Thus, TSP. 3: branch and bound should be easy enough to implement

Comment: Do you want a walk, trail or path? In other words can you pass one edge/vertex more than once?

Comment: @usamec: You can pass edges and vertices more than once, but please see my second note.

Comment: Well. Other direction (finding smallest time to collect all rewards) is chinese postman problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem), which can be solved by using minimum perfect matching (you need to find paths between vertices with odd degree).

Comment: It's at least weakly NP-hard by reduction from knapsack.

Answer (score 0):

This one reminded me this well known NP-hard problem
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

The problem you denoted must be NP-hard too.

Comment: Then reduce every longest path problem to this one!

Comment: You can't really say something is NP-hard because it reminds you of an NP-hard problem. You need to, as usamec stated, reduce solving the longest path problem to this one (in a generic way). Perhaps this would've been better suited as a comment (which you can do, since you have 50 reputation), not an answer (and perhaps 'is likely' instead of 'must be').

Comment: (Hint: Set all the times to 0, all the costs to 1, and see if there is a simple path with profit n - 1.)

Comment: Problem 1 is reducted easily. Isn't it ?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Doesn't work, this doesn't enforce simple path, because you still can visit one vertex more than once. mr_esp: Then show the reduction.